# Videos about Linux and Open Source

Tags: linux, unix, open-source, video, history

I'm looking for some videos about the history of Unix/Linux and Open Source Software. I know (and have) [Revolution OS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000A9GLO).

Are there any others?

Edit: I'm a teacher and need resources to show students.

Edit: I found Revolution OS on [Google Video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=7707585592627775409).

Answer (score 5):

Stephen Fry wished GNU a happy birthday [here](http://www.gnu.org/fry/), its a neat watch. I think your question obviates the need for more videos that explain entanglements that occur frequently in the FLOSS community.

Please also understand that 'open source' and 'free software' can mean different things, depending on who you are speaking with.

Most interesting discussions happen on mailing lists, not Youtube or similar.

You might also enjoy these videos [regarding GPL3](http://gplv3.fsf.org/av).

Most people who get more done through code rather than speaking do not enjoy making videos. That is not a slam against RMS, geeks like to be stored in cool, dark, dry places unless activism is what makes them happy.

A simple search on any of these names in conjunction with 'software license' should turn up more:

- Richard Stallman
- Linus Torvalds
- Theo De Raadt

Wikipedia has good info on all of the above.

Again, not a slam on RMS, but anyone making a video discussing an idealistic topic has some ideal to sell you. Videos alone are not the best way of learning the politics that divide the FLOSS community almost as much as software patents. Do some real reading and research.

Just, whatever you do, don't write your own license, see [license proliferation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_proliferation) for more.